# Prevent Widows10 taskbar search to search in online resources

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, windows-search

I don't want to see something like this:
[image]

Let's say I would like to restrict the search only on applications. Or applications and local files, local documents.

I conside it very dangerous. I have already entered some relatively sensitive data there by mystake. And with that they entered remote logs of some external seach engine.

I think it's powered by Bing. In that case my question can be aslo formulated as how to prevent integration of taskbar search, or start menu search, and Bing.

Comment: I do not think you can turn Web search all the way off. You can open Search, click on the the three dots ... upper right, Settings gear and then use the setting for Strict Web search (reduces results) and then explore Bing Privacy and Search settings.

Comment: What is the current value of `BingSearchEnabled` and `DisableSearchBoxSuggestions` within your registry.  What version of Windows 10 are you using?  Please [edit] your question to include this vital necessary information.